# Probably an easy javascript question regarding classes

Tags: javascript

How can I get  `getElementsByClassName` to work? Want to replace `getElementById` which is working just fine, but need to fetch classes instead.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/G1111/pen/YzRqreV)

HTML:

```
<div class="spinner-displayer3"></div>    
<div id="something"  class="something2">Click orange box!</div>
```

CSS:

```
#something, .something2 {
  margin:150px 0 0 150px;
  background-color:orange;
  width:130px;
}
   
.loading2 {
position:fixed;                      
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:1000001;
width:100%; 
height:100%;
background-image: url("https://tradinglatam.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/loading-gif-png-4.gif");
border: 2px solid #ccc;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
background-color: white;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
```

**Now to the JS...**

...Working JSS (fetching ID):

```
function spinner() {
   const spinnerDisplayer = document.querySelector(".spinner-displayer3");
   const btn = document.getElementById("something");

   btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   spinnerDisplayer.classList.add("loading2");

 })
}     
spinner();
```

...Not working JS (fetching class):

```
function spinner() {
   const spinnerDisplayer = document.querySelector(".spinner-displayer3");
   const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("something2");

   btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   spinnerDisplayer.classList.add("loading2");
 
 })
}     
spinner();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns a single HTML element, but [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (comparable to an array, hence the plural form of element**s**) of HTML elements. You should access the first element in the return value of `getElementsByClassName` (note `[0]` at the end):

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("something2")[0];
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your answer. Even though the question was easy, it does not take away the fact that you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake, but `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` (just think of an array here).
If you want to get the first element with className of `something2` you can do

```js
btn = document.getElementsByClassName("something2")[0];
btn.on...
```

The main use of getting by className instead of id is that you can have multiple elements with the same className. You can do something for each element with a certain classname like this

```js
Object.values(document.getElementsByClassName("something2")).forEach(btn => {
    btn.on...
});
```

Comment: This only works for the first class...how can I make it work for many classes [0-100]?

Comment: Look at the second example, it will run for each element

Comment: Yes, but I am new to javascript...will try.